# Sequence of more than one item of normalize-space

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

I have to get the content of an element, which has also has xml-tags inbetween the content of the element. Due to this, I got as a result a sequence of items, which makes a problem, because I have to pass the result to the normalize-space function, which not allows a sequence of more than one item. Here is the error message:

"A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of normalize-space() ("Hello...", "world", ...)"

XSL code:

```
<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(preceding-sibling::node()/text())"/>
```

XML:

```
<title>Hello
        <tag1>world</tag1>
            Hello2<tag1><tag2>world2
            Hello3</tag2></tag1><tag1><tag2>world3
            Hello4</tag2><tag3>world4
    Hello5</tag3></tag1></title>
```

I'm searching for a simple way to make the result sequence of string into one string, which I can use for the normalize-space function. Something as the toString() function. But I'm open for any good suggestion, which could solve my problem!

Comment: So what is the context node for your `xsl:value-of` in that posted XML input snippet? Which value do you want to output? If you want to get the complete content of an element (the `title` element?) then I would suggest to select that element and use `normalize-space` on the element node itself.

Comment: you are right, the context node is `title`

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my issue, by changing the term to this:
`<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(preceding-sibling::title)"/>`

Comment: It will still fail if there is more than one preceding sibling called "title".

Answer (score 0):

I think you are something misunderstand about context node condition. But if `title` element is truly the context node, the most simple way to get the normalized string value of `title` element is to use `normalize-space(string(.))`. The `string(.)` returns the string value of context node.

[input]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<title>Hello
    <tag1>world</tag1>
    Hello2<tag1><tag2>world2
        Hello3</tag2></tag1><tag1><tag2>world3
            Hello4</tag2><tag3>world4
                Hello5</tag3></tag1></title>
```

[stylesheet]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="title">
        <result>
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(string(.))"/>
        </result>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[result]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><result>Hello world Hello2world2 Hello3world3 Hello4world4 Hello5</result>
```